# Where can I find the Animation of a Maui button?

Tags: c#, maui

I would like to create my own button and use the animation for a click as the default button in MAUI. I checked the [Button.cs class](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Button/Button.cs) and found

```
protected internal override void ChangeVisualState()
{
    if (IsEnabled && IsPressed)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, ButtonElement.PressedVisualState);
    }
    else
    {
        base.ChangeVisualState();
    }
}
```

In [ButtonElement.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Button/ButtonElement.cs) you find

```
public const string PressedVisualState = "Pressed";
```

which is not part of the common states in [VisualStateManager.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/VisualStateManager.cs)

```
public class CommonStates
{
    public const string Normal = "Normal";
    public const string Disabled = "Disabled";
    public const string Focused = "Focused";
    public const string Selected = "Selected";
    public const string PointerOver = "PointerOver";
    internal const string Unfocused = "Unfocused";
}
```

**but I can't figure out where the actual state definition is located.**

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve? Your description is quite broad and the problem isn't clear. Have you tried using a [custom animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/animation/custom)?

Comment: @Julian I would like to make a button that can contain other stuff, like checkboxes, images, etc. as well as text which should overall still look and act like a normal button. For this I thought about making my own ContentView, which is a border that contains the child elements. I'd like to use the same behaviour on the border as when I click on a normal button.

Comment: You can define [custom Visual States](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states#define-custom-visual-states) in XAML

Comment: @Julian yes I know, that's why I'm looking for the original definitions so I can copy them. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I would expect those definitions to be platform-specific, since buttons use native controls on each platform.

Answer (score 4):

Meanwhile you are looking for another solution you can make those ripple effects yourself by using `Graphics` and `AnimationManager`

With AnimationManager you run [Animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/animation/custom) in a controlled manner. There are a lot of implementations out there to get the ripple effect you can see on many buttons and controls.

In the control you need a `GraphicsView` and a Drawable class connected to that.

In your `GraphicsView` you control the animation and invoke the `Invalidate`

```cs
internal async Task AnimateRippleEffect()
{
    float start = 0;
    float end = 1;

    _animationManager?.Add(new Microsoft.Maui.Animations.Animation(callback: (progress) =>
    {
        _drawable.AnimationPercent = start.Lerp(end, progress);
         Invalidate();
    }, duration: 0.4, easing: Easing.SinInOut,
    finished: () =>
    {
        _drawable.AnimationPercent = 0;
    }));

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In the Drawable you put the effect you want

```cs
public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
{

    canvas.SaveState();
    
    canvas.FillColor = myGraphicsView.Color.WithAlpha(0.75f * (1 - (float)_animationPercent));
    
    canvas.Alpha = 0.55f;
    
    float minimumRippleEffectSize = 0.0f;
    
    var rippleEffectSize = minimumRippleEffectSize.Lerp(dirtyRect.Width * 0.65f, _animationPercent);
    
    canvas.FillCircle((float)center.X, (float)center.Y, rippleEffectSize);
    
    canvas.RestoreState();

}
```

This start when you press the button

```cs
private static async void OnButtonClicked(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    if ((bool)newValue)
    {
        await ((MyGraphicsView)bindable).AnimateRippleEffect();
    }
}
```

This can look like this:

[image]

The source code can be found in my [Repo](https://github.com/PeterWessberg/MAUISamples/tree/main)